# Error while building sodor emulators, riscv-sodor

Tags: makefile, riscv, chisel

I installed riscv,riscv-gnu-toolchain and riscv-tools and want to get riscv-sodor. To do that i followed the steps from https://github.com/librecores/riscv-sodor , succesfully installed verilator and  front-end server but after that i have to build sodor emulators and on first step by doing make command i got this error

```
make -C emulator/rv32_1stage/
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/nemanja/riscv-sodor/emulator/rv32_1stage'
verilator --cc --exe  --top-module Top +define+PRINTF_COND=\$c\(\"verbose\"\) --assert --output-split 20000 --x-assign unique -I/home/nemanja/riscv-sodor/vsrc -O3 -CFLAGS " -O1 -std=c++11  -g -I/home/nemanja/riscv-sodor/emulator/common -I/home/nemanja/riscv-sodor/riscv-fesvr  -L/opt/riscv/lib -Wl,-rpath,/opt/riscv/lib -L. -lpthread -DVERILATOR -include /home/nemanja/riscv-sodor/emulator/common/verilator.h" \
-o /home/nemanja/riscv-sodor/emulator/rv32_1stage/emulator generated-src/Top.v /home/nemanja/riscv-sodor/vsrc/SimDTM.v -LDFLAGS " -L/opt/riscv/lib -Wl,-rpath,/opt/riscv/lib -L. -lpthread" /home/nemanja/riscv-sodor/emulator/common/emulator.cpp /home/nemanja/riscv-sodor/riscv-fesvr/build/libfesvr.so /home/nemanja/riscv-sodor/emulator/rv32_1stage/SimDTM.o
/bin/sh: 1: verilator: not found
/home/nemanja/riscv-sodor/emulator/common/Makefile.include:83: recipe for target 'emulator' failed
make[1]: *** [emulator] Error 127
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/nemanja/riscv-sodor/emulator/rv32_1stage'
Makefile:104: recipe for target 'emulator/rv32_1stage/emulator' failed
make: *** [emulator/rv32_1stage/emulator] Error 2
```

Because i am really new to this all, i don't have any idea what could be problem.
I would appreciate any possible help in troubleshooting...

Thank you.

Comment: As the answer below states, the first error message indicates what is wrong, which is that you haven't installed one of the documented dependencies (verilator).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That specific error is due to `verilator` not being installed and on your `$PATH`.

```
/bin/sh: 1: verilator: not found
```

Once you get that installed for your operating system, you should get past this specific issue.